# Add new column based on min of two other columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which looks like below

```
id  id1 seq_nbr     id2 orig_id1  orig_id2  
1   740     2       217     740     217         
1   740     3       216     740     216
1   740     4       216     740     216
1   740     5       217     740     217
1   367     1       217     740     217
```

I need to add new column called orig_seq_nbr based on orig_id1, orig_id2. The expected output is

```
id  id1 seq_nbr     id2 orig_id1  orig_id2 orig_seq_nbr
1   740     3       216     740     216         3
1   740     4       216     740     216         3
1   740     5       217     740     217         2
1   367     1       217     740     217         2
1   740     2       217     740     217         2
```

First two rows have 3 because orig_id1, orig_id2 have 740,216 and the min of seq_nbr based on id1,id2 columns (740,216) is 3.
Last three rows have 2 because orig_id1, orig_id2 have 740,217 and the min of seq_nbr based on id1,id2 columns (740,217) is 2.

I tried to find the min based on orig_id1, orig_id2 but got the result below

```
val win = Window.partitionBy("orig_id1", "orig_id2")
df1.withColumn("orig_seq_nbr",min(col("seq_nbr")).over(win)).show()
```

```
id  id1 seq_nbr     id2 orig_id1  orig_id2 orig_seq_nbr
1   740     3       216     740     216         3
1   740     4       216     740     216         3
1   740     5       217     740     217         1
1   367     1       217     740     217         1
1   740     2       217     740     217         1
```

What should I change to get orig_seq_nbr as 2 for the last three rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach-

### 1. Load the test Data

```scala
val data =
      """
        |id | id1 | seq_nbr   |  id2 |orig_id1 | orig_id2
        |1  | 740 |     2     |  217 |    740  |   217
        |1  | 740 |     3     |  216 |    740  |   216
        |1  | 740 |     4     |  216 |    740  |   216
        |1  | 740 |     5     |  217 |    740  |   217
        |1  | 367 |     1     |  217 |    740  |   217
      """.stripMargin

    val stringDS1 = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df1 = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS1)
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+---+-------+---+--------+--------+
      * |id |id1|seq_nbr|id2|orig_id1|orig_id2|
      * +---+---+-------+---+--------+--------+
      * |1  |740|2      |217|740     |217     |
      * |1  |740|3      |216|740     |216     |
      * |1  |740|4      |216|740     |216     |
      * |1  |740|5      |217|740     |217     |
      * |1  |367|1      |217|740     |217     |
      * +---+---+-------+---+--------+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- id1: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- seq_nbr: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- id2: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- orig_id1: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- orig_id2: integer (nullable = true)
      */
```

### 2. Using DSL

```scala
 val win = Window.partitionBy("orig_id1", "orig_id2")
    df1.withColumn("orig_seq_nbr",
      min(when($"orig_id1" === $"id1" && $"orig_id2" === $"id2", $"seq_nbr").otherwise(null))
      .over(win)
    ).show()

    /**
      * +---+---+-------+---+--------+--------+------------+
      * | id|id1|seq_nbr|id2|orig_id1|orig_id2|orig_seq_nbr|
      * +---+---+-------+---+--------+--------+------------+
      * |  1|740|      3|216|     740|     216|           3|
      * |  1|740|      4|216|     740|     216|           3|
      * |  1|740|      2|217|     740|     217|           2|
      * |  1|740|      5|217|     740|     217|           2|
      * |  1|367|      1|217|     740|     217|           2|
      * +---+---+-------+---+--------+--------+------------+
      */
```

### 3. Using SQL expressions

```scala
 df1.withColumn("orig_seq_nbr",
      expr("min(case when orig_id1=id1 and orig_id2=id2 then seq_nbr else NULL end) " +
        "OVER (PARTITION BY orig_id1, orig_id2) ")
    ).show()

    /**
      * +---+---+-------+---+--------+--------+------------+
      * | id|id1|seq_nbr|id2|orig_id1|orig_id2|orig_seq_nbr|
      * +---+---+-------+---+--------+--------+------------+
      * |  1|740|      3|216|     740|     216|           3|
      * |  1|740|      4|216|     740|     216|           3|
      * |  1|740|      2|217|     740|     217|           2|
      * |  1|740|      5|217|     740|     217|           2|
      * |  1|367|      1|217|     740|     217|           2|
      * +---+---+-------+---+--------+--------+------------+
      */
```